# How to encrypt a stream in node js

Tags: node.js, encryption, node-streams, nodejs-stream, node-crypto

How to encrypt and decrypt a stream in node js without saving the file locally or converting it into buffer.
if there is no way then pls provide memory efficient and less storage consuming way to encrypt and decrypt stream in node js so that i can directly upload stream to google drive through api .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i got solution to this question . I am posting the answer here for everyone who need this

I am using a library called [aes-encrypt-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aes-encrypt-stream)

 or you can use crpto library as well or any other.
Here

> use stream.PassThrough
>
>  Here **file.stream** is my input stream
>
> **stream** is my outputstream
>
>  From this code i am able to reduce memory consumption of server for encryption

```
const { createEncryptStream, createDecryptStream, setPassword } = require('aes-encrypt-stream');
setPassword(Buffer.from('your key here', 'hex'));
PassThroughStream = require('stream').PassThrough,
stream = new PassThroughStream();
await createEncryptStream(file.stream).pipe(stream);
```

now stream is encrypted